# Firefox : automatically fill form on page load?

Tags: firefox, form-fill

Is there a way for Firefox to automatically fill matching input box (text, radio, checkbox....) and textarea on page loading without the need of clicking anything like RoboForm & iMacros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an **Auto Fill** feature in the latest copy of Robo Form.